# Need Help Running a Shell Script in IBM AIX

Tags: bash, aix

we have a shell script which we are trying to run as `$>./shell.sh`. On running this we get a error about a "bad interpreter". on running the script as `sh shell.sh` it runs. my question is can we run a shell script in IBM AIX as `./shell.sh`.

we have a lot of shell scripts which call other scripts. changing the shell scripts to call the other shell scripts as `sh other_shell_scripts.sh` is not feasible.

note we are using the bash shell as the default shell

Comment: What's the first line of your script?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a script with `./shell.sh` it *must* have a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as the first line, for example `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/sh`.

If you do have a shebang line, check that it's correctly formatted and that your files do not contain DOS newlines (`\r\n`, aka `CRLF`). You can use `dos2unix` to fix such files.